# Write a catch to display usernames that are not in AD

Tags: powershell, foreach, try-catch, export-to-csv

I would like to write a line that lets me know any usernames that could not be found and what their display name was within the .txt document that the script is pulling from.

Essentially I just want a line to add onto the existing script.

Any tips or guidance on how to do so would be much appriciated.

```
Get-Content C:\Users\User\Desktop\findusername.txt | Foreach-Object {get-aduser -filter "displayName -like '$($_)'" | Select-Object SamAccountName} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\User\Documents\ADGroupusernames.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: AD Filter doesn't throw when it can't find an object. You want to check for null instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Santiago points out, filter does not throw an error when no matching objects are found.  You can instead check to see if any objects are returned and react to that.

```
Get-Content C:\Users\User\Desktop\findusername.txt | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        if ($found = Get-ADUser -Filter "displayName -like '$($_)'") {
            $found | Select-Object SamAccountName
        }
        else {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                SamAccountName = "Did not find '$_'"
            }
        } 
    } | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\User\Documents\ADGroupusernames.csv -NoTypeInformation
```